# Is using an int as a primary key a security risk?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have read a lot of articles on the "int vs GUID for primary key" question and can see that if you use a sequential GUID you don't need to worry about performance too much.

The reason my boss wants to use GUIDs is that he feels it's more secure. We encrypt all parameters into an MVC call so I'm not sure I see the issue but his main argument is that, armed with one key (assuming they can break the encryption), then it's easy to guess the next key. You can't do this with a GUID, even with pseudo-sequential GUIDs such as COMBs (http://csharptest.net/1250/why-guid-primary-keys-are-a-databases-worst-nightmare/).

But is using an int really that insecure? (We encrypt with Triple DES.) Is there any mileage in making int64 primary keys "almost sequential" - i.e. they always go up but leave gaps in the sequence?

If anyone has any observations about the security side of this I'd be grateful.

Comment: The choice of key type has nothing whatsoever to do with security. Ugliness of a key isn't related to security

Comment: If you are really concerned about security, then use stored procs and give access only to the execution of the procs and no direct access to the tables, views or other objects. Then even if they guess the id, what they can do with it is very limited.

Comment: Using an `INT` is no less secure than using a GUID - you just have to check that if a user X request e.g. info about account `42` that he's actually entitled / allowed to see that info.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments and answers. It's nice to know my own thinking isn't too far removed from sanity. I think this subject is one where FUD definitely plays a part! My boss is pretty set on GUIDs so I expect that's we'll be doing. Just seems a shame if there's no overriding reason for it. As has been said more than once in the responses - check the user can see what he's trying to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key security is about preventing users from be able to access someone elses items. If you use ints in an url you can simply replace your id with a near one. For instance if your url is  `http://mysite/someresource/1/` you could replace it with `http://mysite/someresource/2/`.

With GUIDs that is a lot harder since it takes a magnitude more attempts to find another id. However, it's like lotto. You can be lucky. Thus it's still not secure.

The only secure way is to each time check if the user is authorized to access the requested resource or not.

I do not know why you encrypt the parameters? If it's to limit access it's not very secure. Someone could still just pass it on to someone else (copy/paste) and that other person can access it. Social engineering.

Answer (score 1):

If a user wants to access resource "1" or "2" you have to check if he has permission to access it. This would be the same if you use Guid "A" or "B".

Answer (score 1):

you could use both, int for internal use (if you are worrying about performance) and GUID for external (for example in web urls of your web services), you may also benefit from GUID if you have cross site objects (for example items across several stores that transfer in between them), guid could serve as a global identifier.